# What's the difference between .from() and .of() from an existing map?

Tags: arrays, sorting, dart

In Dart, these both are possible.

```
Map<String, int> map1 = {'zero': 0, 'one': 1, 'two': 2};

Map map2 = Map.from(map1);
print(map2);

Map map3 = Map.of(map1);
print(map3);
```

And they output this.

```
{zero: 0, one: 1, two: 2}
{zero: 0, one: 1, two: 2}
```

So, what's the difference between the two?

Maybe it's something to do with the way they copy, any help is appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Map.from()` and `Map.of()` are redirected to `LinkedHashMap<K, V>.from` and `LinkedHashMap<K, V>.of` respectively.
Below is the source code of `.from()` and `.of()` of LinkedHashMap.

```dart
/// Creates a [LinkedHashMap] that contains all key value pairs of [other].
///
/// The keys must all be instances of [K] and the values to [V].
/// The [other] map itself can have any type.
factory LinkedHashMap.from(Map other) {
  LinkedHashMap<K, V> result = LinkedHashMap<K, V>();
  other.forEach((k, v) {
    result[k] = v;
  });
  return result;
}

/// Creates a [LinkedHashMap] that contains all key value pairs of [other].
factory LinkedHashMap.of(Map<K, V> other) =>
    LinkedHashMap<K, V>()..addAll(other);
```

As written in the comments and as you can see from the code, `.from()` accepts a map with any key/value types, whereas `.of()` can accept only `Map<K, V>`.

```dart
void main() async {
  Map<String, int> map1 = {'zero': 0, 'one': 1, 'two': 2};

  final map2 = Map<String, double>.from(map1);
  print(map2); // {'zero': 0, 'one': 1, 'two': 2}

/*
  // This fails because the passed map is not Map<String, double> but Map<String, int>.
  final map2 = Map<String, double>.of(map1);
*/

  final map3 = Map<String, int>.of(map1);
  print(map3); // {'zero': 0, 'one': 1, 'two': 2}
}
```